# How to record calls without the help of loud speaker in android

Tags: android

Am a beginner in android and I currently working in a project for to record the incoming and outgoing calls in android, but I can't hear receiver voice and I can hear only the dial-er voice. If I switch on the loud speaker then I can hear both the voices. But that's not what I need, I want to record each side of voices clearly without the help of loud speaker. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Recording calls can be a challenge as many manufacturers don't allow it(due to legal issues).

For the ones who do you need to access mic via VOICE_CALL permission in manifest to record calls.

use:

audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL

Comment: thanks for your answer but am a beginner in android, I can't do the coding by using this answer, could you please provide me the full source...